# Julia ERROR: no process with id 2 exists

Tags: julia, jupyter, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to run Julia on multiple cores:

starting in a command line (4 cores):
$ /Applications/Julia-0.5.app/Contents/Resources/julia/bin/julia -p 4

How to enforce multicore in Jupyter?

Answer (score 2):

Use `addprocs(N)` with N as the number of new processes you would like to start.

See here http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/stdlib/parallel/#Base.addprocs

and here http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/?highlight=addprocs

Comment: https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/stdlib/parallel/#General-Parallel-Computing-Support-1